# ggplot2 - Manually specifying boxplot facet labels as symbol/math expressions

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot, facet

I have a `tibble` data frame called `my_data` that looks like this:

```
> my_data
# A tibble: 60 x 4
   SPECIES       simulation_id psi_hat p_hat
   <chr>                 <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Grey squirrel            74   0.527 0.306
 2 Grey squirrel           102   0.526 0.316
 3 Grey squirrel           142   0.527 0.309
 4 Grey squirrel           121   0.527 0.309
 5 Grey squirrel            25   0.526 0.317
 6 Grey squirrel            50   0.527 0.309
 7 Grey squirrel            67   0.491 0.326
 8 Grey squirrel            19   0.527 0.306
 9 Grey squirrel           174   0.527 0.302
10 Grey squirrel            46   0.527 0.309
# ... with 50 more rows
```

There are three different `SPECIES` in `my_data`.

I want to make a boxplot of the `psi_hat` and `p_hat` variables for each `SPECIES`. I started by preparing my `tibble` like so:

```
my_data_plot <- my_data %>% 
    gather("psi_hat", "p_hat", key = "parameter", value = "estimate")
```

Then plotting it like this:

```
ggplot(data = my_data_plot, mapping = aes(x = SPECIES)) +
    geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(y = estimate)) + 
    facet_grid(. ~ parameter)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

What I want to do now is to label the facets as actual Greek symbols rather than e.g. "psi_hat" so that "psi_hat" would get the symbol equivalent to `expression(hat(psi))` in the facet label.

I am aware that in `facet_grid` I could use `labeller = label_parse`, but that means my variable names have to be actual expressions, but I don't know how to do that when the variable names have to be a function call (i.e. `hat(psi)`). For example, I tried `my_data <- my_data %>% rename(hat(psi) = "psi_hat")` which gives me this error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"my_data <- my_data %>% 
    rename(hat(psi) ="
```

I also considered `labeller = bquote`, but that seems to require me to specify rows *and* columns when I only have columns in this plot.

So, I am wondering if there is a need, or way, for me to manually define expressions for those facet labels? Or is there a more algorithmic way of achieving this?

Thank you!

Here is the `dput()` of `my_data`:

```
structure(list(SPECIES = c("Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", 
"Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", 
"Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", 
"Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", 
"Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", 
"Grey squirrel", "Grey squirrel", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", 
"Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", 
"Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", 
"Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Red fox", "Roe Deer", 
"Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", 
"Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", 
"Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", "Roe Deer", 
"Roe Deer"), simulation_id = c(74L, 102L, 142L, 121L, 25L, 50L, 
67L, 19L, 174L, 46L, 162L, 31L, 199L, 147L, 163L, 18L, 170L, 
172L, 106L, 157L, 158L, 200L, 187L, 103L, 144L, 77L, 78L, 139L, 
75L, 57L, 171L, 195L, 90L, 136L, 109L, 30L, 152L, 97L, 74L, 8L, 
161L, 73L, 130L, 151L, 150L, 184L, 198L, 177L, 97L, 88L, 123L, 
190L, 83L, 75L, 143L, 159L, 103L, 16L, 200L, 2L), psi_hat = c(0.526863413764263, 
0.525835491514182, 0.526515540307052, 0.526515540305866, 0.525668605170743, 
0.526515540309525, 0.491205525300549, 0.526863413760793, 0.527216807861263, 
0.526515540305866, 0.526515540306427, 0.526003604543373, 0.526003604547465, 
0.527039406294591, 0.491512271725946, 0.526343604414775, 0.526515540311415, 
0.490421555053814, 0.526003604541449, 0.526688801109048, 0.79766843868635, 
0.801911295111649, 0.797668438685209, 0.79766843868356, 0.736091175845588, 
0.801911294988272, 0.797668438684876, 0.797668438686537, 0.764665429923081, 
0.806326437262252, 0.769630414385322, 0.806326437300003, 0.733141462334417, 
0.801911295128621, 0.777085591061084, 0.801911295171974, 0.703578316906639, 
0.777085591642251, 0.793615265014951, 0.806326437459794, 0.662677377511043, 
0.701654360968483, 0.704629679152389, 0.70622149033349, 0.663754148939585, 
0.704629679094459, 0.705416487515374, 0.677464341430293, 0.707045218951227, 
0.662338556587023, 0.674456696561803, 0.701654360967044, 0.639650521202062, 
0.625380503760432, 0.704629679094605, 0.664561357366103, 0.704629679143759, 
0.636859548660175, 0.66375414894085, 0.707045219029558), p_hat = c(0.305763297214646, 
0.315819064091298, 0.309115591855344, 0.309115591855175, 0.317494717397372, 
0.309115591855145, 0.326303719905328, 0.305763297214592, 0.302410595448716, 
0.309115591855175, 0.309115591855139, 0.314143327866378, 0.314143327866402, 
0.304086998925611, 0.322825888575185, 0.310791594807592, 0.309115591855151, 
0.335654773573103, 0.314143327866529, 0.307439493743849, 0.0690109229482788, 
0.0677020110780009, 0.0690109229483345, 0.0690109229474338, 0.0744703724155286, 
0.0677020110840996, 0.0690109229257095, 0.0690109229256593, 0.0704604468308165, 
0.0663903378649822, 0.0691283355131073, 0.0663903378091044, 0.0737444081467713, 
0.0677020110873479, 0.0665479524846632, 0.0677020110750217, 0.073966658329169, 
0.0665479525245426, 0.0703192747621257, 0.0663903375835434, 0.166196509352831, 
0.157146399287494, 0.152026850762839, 0.14946227707946, 0.163675003941755, 
0.152026850344473, 0.150744974403108, 0.15740696035152, 0.148178744896067, 
0.167783160277052, 0.162569260757996, 0.157146399287514, 0.162501076719809, 
0.177160578693552, 0.152026850344548, 0.162149934290892, 0.152026850679299, 
0.168221557280052, 0.163675003941561, 0.148178745461308)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this. Because your data is in long format, I use `case_when` to rename the variables with an expression to be read by the labeller

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    gather(key = "parameter", value = "estimate", -SPECIES, -simulation_id) %>%
  mutate(parameter = case_when(
    parameter == "psi_hat" ~ "hat(psi)",
    parameter == "p_hat" ~ "hat(p)"
  )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = SPECIES)) +
    geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(y = estimate)) + 
    facet_grid(. ~ parameter, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-18 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you very much @AndS it worked for me. Great use of `case_when()` that I haven't thought of before. And thanks for teaching me about [`reprex`](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/), too. Very useful!